# Skip serializing a list element if a condition is satisfied (Newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft for serialization and I want to skip serializing a specific element in a list.

Say, I have a class:

```
public class Car
{
    public PropertyA A {get; set;}
    public PropertyB B {get; set;}
    public bool ShouldSerializeCar {get; set;}
}
```

And I have an Action method that returns a `List<Car>` as a reponse like:

```
    [HttpGet("cars", Name = "GetCars")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Car>), 200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCars()
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        //Some code here that generates a list of Car//
        return cars;
    }
```

When Newtonsoft serializes the response, is it possible to skip serializing list items where `ShouldSerializeCar` is false?

Please note that I cannot use another library except Newtonsoft as it has been used all over the project.

Comment: Serializer is for serialization ... it may skip unwanted properties not elements from collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on Newtonsoft to do this why would you not filter your list before serializing your list?

code:

```
[HttpGet("cars", Name = "GetCars")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Car>), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCars()
{
    var cars = _repo.GetCars().Where(c => c.ShouldSerializeCar );
    retur Ok(cars);
}
```